# ajax has got memory leak?

Tags: ajax, memory-leaks

ajax tutorial on w3school at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

In this function (function GetXmlHttpObject()), it creates a object:

```
 new XMLHttpRequest(); or new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

but it doesn't delete this object after getting respons from server.

Are there memory leaks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok - Garbage Collection will pick it up for you.

Comment: BTW, still that ajax tutorial on w3school at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp,  on the ASP page, response.expires=-1, is that important?

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector will take care of it once it is no longer referenced.